Extract previous row calculated value for use in current row calculations - SQL
I have a table as shown here, with expected output in column result:
id  col1   col2   col3  result
------------------------------
1   10     30     2     30
2   15     10     8     28
3   25     10     5     25
4   20     25     9     25
5   30     15     4     30

Formula for result is:
result = max(col1, col2, (previous_row's) result - (previous row's) col3)

For example: for the first row, it's max(10, 30) = 30 and for second row it's max(15, 10, 30-2) = 28
Can this be done in SQL efficiently using partition?
I have figured out a way to do this part:
 ((previous_row's) result - (previous row's) col3)

but I'm stuck because of the complexity involving max function using value from its previous row as an input.
Update: I use this sql to get ((previous_row's) result - (previous row's) col3):
FIRST_VALUE(max(col1, col2)) OVER (ORDER BY id)
    - IFNULL(SUM(col3) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0)) 


why don't you show us how far you got. but if you git that part right , you probably only looking for greatest() function instead of max()

Updated my question with what I have got. I too initially thought greatest() is what I need but it doesn't look like that straightforward. When Max function choses either of col1 or col2 it puts the subsequent flow off (refer to row 3)

Consider below approach
WITH RECURSIVE result_cte AS (
  SELECT *, GREATEST(col1, col2) AS result
  FROM your_table
  WHERE id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*, GREATEST(t.col1, t.col2, r.result - r.col3) AS result
  FROM your_table t
  JOIN result_cte r
  ON t.id = r.id + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM result_cte
ORDER BY id    

if applied to sample dara in your questions, output is

